# Convert XML Response to Python Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xml-parsing

http://stat.data.abs.gov.au/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetDataStructure/all

From the above link we get list of Dataset available in http://www.abs.gov.au/

I need to extract all Dataset Id & names in English & French

KeyFamily id as "Dataset Id"

Name xml:lang="en" as "Dataset Name English"

Name xml:lang="fr" as "Dataset Name French"

From the Table: "message:KeyFamilies"

Source:

[image]

Trying in below code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

URL = 'http://stat.data.abs.gov.au/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetDataStructure/all'

print('\n> Retrieving XML Data:', URL)
XML_Data = requests.get(URL).content
print('>> XML_Data:', len(XML_Data))

def xml2df(XML_Data):
    root = ET.XML(XML_Data) # element tree
    all_records = []
    for i, child in enumerate(root):
    print(i)
    record = {}
    for subchild in child:
        record[subchild.tag] = subchild.text
    all_records.append(record)
    df = pd.DataFrame(all_records)

    return df

df = xml2df(XML_Data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long work below code gives what I expected.

```
import requests, csv
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

URL = 'http://stat.data.abs.gov.au/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetDataStructure/all'

print('\n> Retrieving XML Data:', URL)
XML_DF = requests.get(URL).content
print('>> XML_DF:', len(XML_DF))

root = ET.XML(XML_DF) # element tree
XML_List = []
for child in root[1]:
    XML_Dict = {}
    XML_Dict['Dataset_Id'] = child.attrib['id']
    for subchild in child:
    if ''.join(subchild.attrib.values()) == 'en':
        XML_Dict['Dataset_Name_EN'] = subchild.text
    elif ''.join(subchild.attrib.values()) == 'fr':
        XML_Dict['Dataset_Name_FR'] = subchild.text

    XML_List.append(XML_Dict)
XML_DF = pd.DataFrame(XML_List)

XML_DF.to_csv(r"D:\Sunil_Work\Dataset List.csv", index=False)
```